# UIViewController method from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, methods, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

This is my 1st question in stackoverflow.com.
I'm trying to call upon a method [- (void)alterTime] from ViewController.m in AppDelegate.m. Yes, I have #imported "ViewController.h" in AppDelegate.h. Importing the controller into AppDelegate.m makes no difference. Also, "Background fetch" is ON.

Here is the code inside AppDelegate.m that I'm trying to implement:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
    NSLog(@"Current Time Altered");

    //Get current view controller
    ViewController *mainViewController = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [mainViewController alterTime];

    //Cleanup
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

This is the piece of code giving me problems:

```
[mainViewController alterTime];
```

It states: "No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'alterTime'".

Comment: Show `ViewController.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that error means that it failed to find the method name (selector), in the class `ViewController`.

Make sure in your `ViewController` header you have the `alterTime` method declared there, effectively making it public.

If that is okay, then double check to make sure that your `rootViewController` is of type (owned by) `ViewController`

Comment: Thank you very much. My inattentiveness really let me down this time.

Comment: No problem at all :)  happens

Answer (score 0):

Declare `- (void)alterTime` in your `ViewController.h` file.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (void)alterTime;

@end
```

Comment: Sheesh, my inattention will be the end of me. I feel embarrassed for not seeing that my self. Thank you very much.